# Why is the state in my parent component a step behind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Game.css";

class Game extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    list: ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      play: false,
      random: null,
      user: null,
      winner: false
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      play: !this.state.play
    });
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    //paper beats Rock
    //scissors beats Paper
    // rock beats scissors
    // 1 > 0
    // 2 > 1
    //0 > 2
    if (this.state.winner) {
      return;
    }
    let hasWon;
    let inputIndex = this.props.list.indexOf(event.target.value);
    let ranIndex = this.props.list.indexOf(this.state.random);
    if (
      (inputIndex === 1 && ranIndex === 0) ||
      (ranIndex === 1 && inputIndex === 0)
    ) {
      hasWon = true;
      //  return this.props.list[1];
    } else if (
      (inputIndex === 2 && ranIndex === 1) ||
      (ranIndex === 2 && inputIndex === 1)
    ) {
      hasWon = true;
    } else if (
      (inputIndex === 0 && ranIndex === 2) ||
      (ranIndex === 0 && inputIndex === 2)
    ) {
      hasWon = true;
    }

    console.log(this.props.list.indexOf(this.state.random));
    this.setState({
      user: event.target.value,
      random: this.props.list[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.list.length)
      ],
      winner: hasWon
    });
  }
  render() {
    let game;

    if (this.state.play) {
      game = (
        <div className="Game-userButtons">
          <button
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            name={this.state.user}
            value="rock"
          >
            Rock
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            name={this.state.user}
            value="paper"
          >
            Paper
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            name={this.state.user}
            value="scissors"
          >
            Scissor
          </button>
          <button>Play Again! </button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      game = (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <button>Play </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Rock, paper, scissors </h1>
        <div className="players">
          <div className="user">
            <i className={`fas fa-hand-${this.state.user}`}></i>
          </div>
          <div className="robot">
            <i className={`fas fa-hand-${this.state.random}`}></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        {game}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Game;
```

I am trying to determine the winner of the rock, paper, scissors game by comparing indexes, of the user and the randomly generated one. In the handleClick() I wrote potential conditions to win the game and the indexes that translate to potential winnings. When I console.log the index of this.state.random, the state that renders seems to be one step behind to the state being consoled. So, the conditions are working, but the visual doesn't make any sense. How can I fix this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: You should add a codesandbox to make it easier to help solve your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think i found your issue, it is related with the **this.state.random**. If you check your code in this part:

```
 let ranIndex = this.props.list.indexOf(this.state.random);
```

you are comparing the **randIndex** with the previous random value from the state, i think that instead of taking the value of the state you should create a new random value:

```
let randIndex =  this.props.list[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.list.length)
      ];
```

and just update it after you finish your comparing as you are making in the set state:

```
this.setState({
      user: event.target.value,
      random: randIndex,
      winner: hasWon
    });
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. I also changed the conditionals to a switch case because the if/else was too eh. You helped me realize what state really is!